# Creating a Path with The Right Numbers

Tags: javascript, d3.js

This should have a pretty straightforward and obvious answer, but my research hasn't brought me one. This is the question. This is my path:

```
svg.selectAll(".path")
    .data(data.chartData, function(d){return d.vNm;})
    .enter().append("path")
        .attr("d", function(d){
            return("M " + x(d.vNm) + " " +  y(1200 + d.values.reduce(function(sum, d){return sum + d.amount;},0))
            + " L " + 43 + x(d.vNm) + " " + y(1200 + d.values.reduce(function(sum, d){return sum + d.amount;}, 0))
            + " L " + 21.5 + x(d.vNm) + " " + y(d.values.reduce(function(sum, d){ return sum + d.amount;}, 0)) + " z"
            );
        });
```

As you can see, I'm trying to add 43 and 21.5 to my x(d.vNm). I've tried do to this in several different ways, but to no avail. This is what shows up in the elements when I try: [image]

And the display: [image]

(I don't care about the labels for now, they'll be turned into a legend soon, also I have black rectangles over every bar. I just need the triangles to be in the right spot.)

Comment: When you manipulate a `float` number the ability to represent that number in binary is nearly impossible, if they need to be absolutely perfect you should try truncating or rounding if it will work for your situation of precision

Comment: An example? @iam-decoder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `" L " + 43 + x(d.vNm)` you're asking Javascript to add `43` to the string `" L "`, which will result in `" L 43"`. Then the result of the call to `x` is added in the same way. If you want the numbers to be added as numbers, you need to tell Javascript about the priority order for the addition with extra parentheses:

```
" L " + (43 + x(d.vNm))
```

On a general note, you shouldn't need to manually add something to the output of a scale -- the same can be achieved by adjusting the range of the scale.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a bunch.